# Find area of exponential function over box-like region

Tags: integration, volume

The problem doesn't seem like it should be too difficult, I have a box-like region $B$ defined as:
$$
\begin{align}
0 \le x \le 1\\
0 \le y \le 3\\
0 \le z \le 2
\end{align}
$$
And the function to integrate is:
$$
\int \int \int_B ye^{-xy}dV
$$

So I set about it and did the following:
$$
\begin{align}
&= \int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^1 ye^{-xy}\:dx\:dy\:dz\\
&= - \int_0^2 \int_0^3 \left[e^{-y} \right]_0^1 \:dy\:dz\\
&= - \int_0^2 \int_0^3 e^{-y} - 1\: dy\:dz \\
&= \int_0^2 \left[ e^{-y}-y \right]_0^3\:dz \\
&= \int_0^2 e^{-3} - 3\: dz\\
&= 2\:( e^{-3}-3)
\end{align}
$$
However my homework application states that this is not the correct answer. I am not sure what I did not do correctly. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: When you evaluated the y integral you lost an $e^0$ term.

Comment: Also, I think some signs got muddled during the y-integration.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely missed the $e^0$ term, and I was trying to pull out the negative from the $-e^{-y}$, but it look like I forgot to actually change the sign of the $-y$ term to $+y$. thanks, I'm re-evaluating it now

Comment: @lulu thanks, I have the correct answer now. I've been super un-confident with regions of integration that I didn't think I had setup the problem correctly. Thanks for showing me that it was just some simple stuff and not the actual setup :)

Comment: No problem.  with computations like this it's hard to know when you've made a conceptual error and when you've just dropped a sign.  Good luck!

Comment: You could post your update as an answer-answering your own question is encouraged per the FAQ.  After some delay you will be able to accept the answer showing that you have a good one.  It will then not be on the unanswered queue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my integration as @lulu pointed out.
The correct answer after my integration goof-ups were fixed is $2 (e^{-3} + 2)$, which agrees with [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20integral%20of%20integral%20of%20y*e%5E(-x*y)%20dx%20dy%20dz%20from%200%20to%202%20from%200%20to%203%20from%200%20to%201&dataset=).